# EntityFramework Fluent API map a class as a composite key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a class that has a composite key defined as a seperate class.

```
public class ClassA : Entity
{
    public virtual ClassACompositeKey CompositeKey { get; set; }
}

public class ClassACompositeKey
{
    public int ThisId { get; set; }

    public int ThatId { get; set; }

    public int OtherId { get; set; }
}
```

Having some difficulty mapping this using fluent api for entity framework. I have tried creating a complex type configuration for the composite class with no luck. When I attempt the mapping as

```
this.HasKey(k => new { k.CompositeKey.ThisId, k.CompositeKey.ThatId, k.CompositeKey.OtherId });
```

I get an error stating that

> The properties expression 'k => new <>f__AnonymousType2 (ThisId = k.CompositeKey.ThisId, ThatId = k.CompositeKey.ThatId, OtherId = k.CompositeKey.OtherId)' is not valid. The expression should represent a property.

I'm somewhat new to EF and Fluent API so I don't even know if this is going to be possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not supported. Key properties must have primitive types (`int`, `long`, `string`, `Guid`, `DateTime`, etc.) and be directly inside the entity class without a wrapping class around them. So you must define a composite key like so:

```
public class ClassA : Entity
{
    public int ThisId { get; set; }

    public int ThatId { get; set; }

    public int OtherId { get; set; }
}
```

... with the Fluent mapping:

```
this.HasKey(k => new { k.ThisId, k.ThatId, k.OtherId });
```